# Will STL deque pop_front() automatically recycle memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl, vector, deque

I have a program in which I collect some data and store them temporarily in a deque

```
    typedef vector<float> floatVector;
    ...
    floatVector * currRecord;
    deque<floatVector *> data;
    ...
    ...

    for (...)
    {
        ...
        currRecord = new floatVector(10); 
        data.push_back(currRecord);
    }
```

Later, I want to save data to file

```
    while (data.size() > 0) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            fprintf(fPtr, "%lf\t", data[0]->at(i) );
        }
    fprintf(fPtr,"\n");
    data.pop_front();
    }
```

So, my question is, will this program cause a memory leak? I use `new` operator to allocate memory for each `currRecord` vector. Will the deque `pop_front` function automatically recycle memory? Or do I need to put

```
    delete [] data[0]
```

before

```
    data.pop_front();
```

? Also, if `data` is a vector instead of a deque, will everything be the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `std::deque` of pointers and each pointer owns a resource (memory). Calling `pop_front()` will remove a pointer from the container but it doesn't release the memory the pointer owns. Since you allocate the memory with `new` you must also call `delete`. The situation is unchanged if the container is a `std::vector`.

You could avoid memory leaks if you changed to a `std::deque<floatvector>` or a container of smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`.

Note that you didn't use `[]` when you called `new` so use plain `delete` without square brackets.