# C++: how to properly pass a variable returned by deque::front() out of a function?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, deque

I am working on a multithreading program where a "std::deque< MyObject > myBuffer" is used as a FIFO buffer, a producer thread is constantly adding custom objects to the end of a deque using push_back(), and a consumer thread uses a helper function to retrieve the object and handle the synchronization and mutex.

```
std::deque< MyObject > myBuffer;
std::mutex mtx;

int main() {
    std::thread producerThread(producer());
    std::thread consumerThread(consumer());

    // other code

    return 0;
}
```

The producer function:

```
void producer() {
    while (somecondition) {

        // code producing MyObject object

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        myBuffer.push_back(object);
    }
}
```

The consumer function:

```
void consumer() {
    while(somecondition) {
        MyObject object1, object2;
        if (retrieve(object1)) {
            // process object1
        }
        if (retrieve(object2)) {
            // process object2
        }
    }
}
```

My current helper function looks like this:

```
bool retrieve(MyObject & object) {
    // other code ...
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    if (!myBuffer.empty()) {
        object = myBuffer.front();
        myBuffer.pop_front();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I quickly realized that deque::front() returns the reference of the first element in the container. And "object" is MyObject&, so based on my understanding, only the reference of the first element in the deque is passed to object and as a result when I call the pop_front(), the element referenced should be gone and the object variable is holding an invalid reference. Surprisingly, when I actually ran the code, everything worked as opposed to what I expected. So could anyone help me understand how this "deque::front() returns the reference" works? Thanks.

Comment: I think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554083/will-stl-deque-pop-front-automatically-recycle-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It works properly and this is expected behavior.**

You don't assign the reference - you can't, C++ references are immutable. You actually copy the value. This is how it is supposed to work. Semantic of `foo = ...` assignment when `foo` is a reference is roughly:
 "copy the right-hand value to the place referenced by `foo`".

When there is a reference on the right side, the referenced value is copied.

In your case, `object = myBuffer.front();` line copies the front value of deque to variable `object1` or `object2` in `consumer()`, respectively to the call. Later call to `.pop_front()` destroys the value in the deque, but doesn't affect the already copied value.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand you purpose,Maybe you can try deque::at()

Comment: The purpose of the retrieve() function is to get the value out of deque for the calling thread to process. It contains all the deque and lock operations so that it can be called at multiple locations in my code and the calling function does not have to worry about the deque and sync management. I need to deque::pop_front() because I do not want the deque to grow indefinitely while my program runs. So using deque::at() cannot achieve my goal here.

Answer (score 0):

pop_front() removes the first element from queue. It does not delete the object. So, referencing the object after pop_front() call should work.

Update -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

class newClass {
public:
    newClass () {
    }

    ~newClass () {
        std::cout << " Destructor is called. " << "\n";
    }

    newClass(const newClass &obj) {
        std::cout << "Copy is called." << "\n";
    }

    void print(void) {
        std::cout << "Hi there !" << "\n";
    }
};

void queueWithPointer(void) {
    std::deque<newClass *> deque;
    deque.push_back(new newClass());
    deque.push_front(new newClass());
    newClass *b = deque.front();
    std::cout << "pop_front starts" << "\n";
    deque.pop_front();
    std::cout << "pop_front ends" << "\n";
    b->print();
}

void queueWithObjects(void) {
    std::deque<newClass> deque;
    deque.push_back(newClass());
    deque.push_front(newClass());
    newClass ba = deque.front();
    std::cout << "pop_front starts" << "\n";
    deque.pop_front();
    std::cout << "pop_front ends" << "\n";
    ba.print();
}

int main()
{
    queueWithPointer();
//  queueWithObjects();

    return 0;
}
```

Above program can be used to understand the behaviour. In case of objects, copy constructor is called and a new copy is stored in deque. When pop_front() is called, the copy is deleted. While in case of pointers, address is copied. So, the address is deleted and not the actual object referenced by the address. You will find that destructor is not called in this case.

Comment: According to [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_front/), pop_front() not only removes the first element from the container but also destroys it.

Comment: Updated the answer to explain it.